# Error: 'I can't write on file 'Main.pdf'

Tags: errors, preamble

I suddenly keep getting the error message in the title. I have no idea what I did wrong as I did not have this problem before. I know this error can occur if the corresponding pdf file is opened, but this is not the case.

When I run biber I get the error: 'Entity: line 1959: parser error : expected '>'

Any ideas on how this can be solved? My preamable is the following:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{table,xcdraw}{xcolor}
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\newcommand{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, maxcitenames = 2, style=authoryear, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{float}
\smartdiagramset{circular distance=4cm,
font=\normalsize,
text width=2.5cm,
arrow line width=0.2cm
}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{%
\smartdiagram[circular diagram]{Insured \\ policy holder,Insurer \\ company}
}

\addbibresource{bib/literature.bib}

\begin{document}[a4paper,12pt]
```

Comment: It is possible that the PDF is not properly constructed because there were fatal errors  during compilation.  The fact that you have `\begin{document}[a4paper,12pt]` is a sign that there likely  are other, more damning errors.  It should just be `\begin{document}` unless you mean to print the `[a4paper,12pt]` in the actual output.  The `\PassOptionsToPackage` is pretty unorthodox too.

Comment: Maybe related with: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240860/i-cant-write-on-file-filename-pdf

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't give more details about the problem (like what compiler are you using), it is hard to found out what is the problem. However, I have reorganized your code, maybe it solves your problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[backend=biber, natbib=true, maxcitenames = 2, style=authoryear, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand{\argmin}{\arg\!\min}
\smartdiagramset{circular distance=4cm,
font=\normalsize,
text width=2.5cm,
arrow line width=0.2cm
}
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{%
\smartdiagram[circular diagram]{Insured \\ policy holder,Insurer \\ company}
}

\addbibresource{bib/literature.bib}

\begin{document}

your text

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reaction. I am using texmaker and miktex. The reorganized code, however, seems not to do the job.

Comment: Some other possible relevent information: when I run biber I get the error: 'Entity: line 1959: parser error : expected '>' </bcf:constrain ^ Entity: line 1959: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: constraint line 1954 and constrain </bcf:constrain ^'. This also was not happening before.

Comment: Did you check your `.bib` file for any invalid entry?